# Can't display images from localhost

Tags: java, image, swing, applet

I dont understand why in my webAPP When I try to load an Icon by doing this for exemple :

```
ImageIcon rtfIcon = new ImageIcon("http://localhost:8080/app/images/rtf.gif");
```

the rtfIcon.getImageLoadStatus() returns an ERRORED value .

But in my web browser it displays properly http://localhost:8080/app/images/rtf.gif .
I dont get it . I use apache tomcat . Is there any option configuration to do or it's simple coding mistake ?

thanks in advance .

Comment: What's the functional requirement? What do you need that `ImageIcon` for? Are you developing an applet or something which needs to show icons from the webapp?

Comment: Yes I am developping an applet .

Comment: Then it has nothing to do with servlets. I've retagged the question so that you get the right attendance. It has been some time ago I did applets, but hardcoding "localhost" in applet code is definitely a bad idea. The applet will fail to work whenever the webserver runs at a physically different machine (in production). Rather use `getCodeBase()` to get the URL to the host where the applet is been served from and then build further on that.

Comment: as a wildest guess, this can be caused by 'headless mode', see here http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/headless/

Comment: I agree it's bad idea ,but I am wondering it isn't working .Servlet tag is better than swing cause even in a servlet `ImageIcon rtfIcon = new ImageIcon("http://localhost:8080/app/images/rtf.gif")` doesn't seem to work . It has something to do with Tomcat I am almost sure .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ImageIcon rtfIcon = new ImageIcon("http://localhost:8080/app/images/rtf.gif");
```

Presumes the `String` refers to a **`File`.**  Use instead..

```
ImageIcon rtfIcon = new ImageIcon(
    new URL("http://localhost:8080/app/images/rtf.gif"));
```

..or, taking into account the advice from BalusC..

> "The applet will fail to work whenever the webserver runs at a physically different machine (in production). Rather use `getCodeBase()` to get the URL to the host where the applet is been served from and then build further on that."

```
ImageIcon rtfIcon = new ImageIcon(
    new URL(getCodeBase(), "/app/images/rtf.gif"));
```

Comment: `ImageIcon rtfIcon = new ImageIcon(
    new URL("http://localhost:8080/app/images/rtf.gif"));
` works fine thanks .I am using my applet in kìnda weird way so I can't use `getCodeBase()`.