# Image not showing in java applet

Tags: java, swing, applet

Before you say this question has been asked, I know and I've read 4 or 5 of the same questions in here but none have helped.

I've tried using getdocumnetbase, getcodebase, buffered images compared to just image,  and everything I've come across so far. Nothing is helping my situation.

My problem is that when I run the applet the image is not showing. I added a button to the applet to see if it shows up but it actually doesnt unless I hover over it or re-size the window.

the only thing the appelt does right now is show the image and button but it's not working. So I'm lost.

Here's the code:

```
public void init() {

    JPanel panel = new JPanel()
    {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)  
        {
            BufferedImage img = null;
            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("..\\gifs\\Assembled.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("inside JPanel");
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);

            super.paintComponent(g); 
        }
    };  

    JButton j = new JButton("hi");
    panel.add(j);
    add(panel);

addMouseListener(this);
repaint();
}
```

thanks.

And now that you've voted this down (and not helped me) lets see if anyone can actually help.

public void init() {

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(){

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)  
    {
         Image i = null;
        try {
            i = getImage(new URL(getCodeBase(), "../gifs/Assembled.jpg"));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("inside JPanel");
        g.drawImage(i, 0, 0, this);

        //super.paintComponent(g); 
    }
    };



    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel.setSize(500,500);
    add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
    addMouseListener(this);
    //repaint();
}
```

I edited the code but still nothing works. The image is found and loaded just fine, but it does not show unless I actively re-size the applet. In other words, the image only shows while it's being re-sized and no other time. Now what would cause that? Oh and it only shows at all if I remove the call to supper.paintComponent(g);.

Oh and your links didn't help seeing as how I've tried the answers before I posted this to begin with.

Comment: *"I know and I've read 4 or 5 of the same questions"*  Which 4 or 5?  And by that I mean links.  I must have answered this question at least twice in the past 72 hours.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Applet image missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256095/applet-image-missing) & [Can't display images from localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989606/cant-display-images-from-localhost/) & [How can I display a bitmap image in a Java applet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045279/how-can-i-display-a-bitmap-image-in-a-java-applet) &..

Comment: *"I added a button to the applet to see if it shows up but it actually doesnt unless I hover over it or re-size the window."* Oh right, another different problem. Replace `repaint();` with `validate();`

Comment: I love how you vote this down AFTER i say I've read the questions already on here and they don't help. I saw the first link, didn't help then, doesn't help now. Second link though I did not think to check (did see it) and it helped only a little.

Now back to the problem.  this code:

The image shows now but only if i re-size it and it only flashes then disappears. It won't stay shown. It basically flashes while I re-size the app then disappears when i stop re-sizing. What would cause that?

Comment: *"I love how you vote this down AFTER.."*  Rubbish!  Just to prove it - here, have MY down-vote.  Good luck with it.  You've just lost the help of the top-ranked answerer for applets.

Comment: This same exact problem of not properly finding the image file for applets has been asked and answered many times on this and other forum. Yours is no different except that you're also trying to read the image from inside the paintComponent method, something that shouldn't be done, ever.

Comment: Funny, cause "the top helper" DIDN'T help, only shot words at me. Oh and it was voted down AFTER I said I looked at those other links. So no it's NOT Rubbish, it's fact.


Also it does find the picture, it simply doesn't keep the image shown. Finding the image isn't a problem, it's keeping it. But since no one here can help, especially mr. "top helper" I'll just scrap the project and find another way to do it.

Comment: Problems been solved. I don't know what the problem was but I made a brand new one and took out the call to super.paintcomponet and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Applets are served by webserver. It's the webbrowser who downloads the Applet code and runs it. So, Applets runs in physically the same machine as where the webbrowser runs.

The following line

```
img = ImageIO.read(new File("..\\gifs\\Assembled.jpg"));
```

expects the file to be present in the local disk file system of the machine where the webbrowser runs, relative to the working directory of the JVM executed by the webbrowser. It does **not** point to a file in the webserver, nor to a file packaged in the Applet's JAR file, if any. You may of course not expect that the enduser has the particular image file already prepared in its local disk file system.

Depending on where the file *actually* is, you need to change that part.

If it's actually stored in the webserver, relative to the URL from where the applet is been downloaded from (which is its *codebase*), then you need to get the file by URL instead.

```
img = ImageIO.read(new URL(getCodeBase(), "gifs/Assembled.jpg"));
```

Imagine that the applet is served by http://example.com/contextname/applet.jar, then the above example assumes the image to be available by http://example.com/contextname/gifs/Assembled.jpg.

Or, if it is actually packaged in the Applet JAR file, then you need to get the file by classpath instead. Imagine that you've stored it in `/META-INF/gifs/Assembled.jpg` of the Applet JAR file, then you need to get it by the classpath as follows:

```
img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/gifs/Assembled.jpg"));
```

By the way, a JPG file is not a GIF file. I'd suggest to rename "gifs" to "images" or something.